# Java junit testing with assertions on objects

Tags: java, unit-testing

the following code is in the setUp() method of class TestSegment:

```
    this.inputSource11 = new InputCell(1, 1);
    this.activeSynapseObject = new Synapse(this.inputSource11);
    this.inputSource11.setActiveState(true);
    this.segmentObject.addSynapse(this.activeSynapseObject);
```

The following is the error in line 95 of TestSegment:

```
public void testGetSynapse()
{
    assertEquals(
        this.activeSynapseObject,
        this.segmentObject.getSynapse(inputSource11));
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show some of the code that you believe is causing this failure?

Comment: You are getting this error because there's a JUnit assertion on line 95 inside the `TestSegment` class. That's all we can conclude by the attached screenshot.

Comment: Can you please share your assertion statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you have put two objects in the assertions. They possess the same value but they are different object instances. I would advice you to define an `equals()` **comparing the field values** method in your object as `assertEquals()` relies upon the equals method as below:

```
 public static void assertEquals(String msg, Object obj1, Object obj2) {
     if (obj1 == null && obj2 == null) {
       return;
     }

     if (obj1 != null && obj1.equals(obj2)) {
       return;
     }

     fail(msg + " expected=" + obj1 + " actual=" + obj2);
 }
```

Comment: Plausible after the recent question update (r2). Congratulations, your guess was correct ;-)